# Paypal Parallel Adaptive Payments: If a refund will occur, how will paypal handle it?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

We opt to use paypal Split payment to pay for our affiliates. In that case we will be using Paypal Parallel Adaptive payment. My question is, how will paypal handle the refund on these transactions? Will the primary receiver pays the 100% amount to the customer asking for refund? Or paypal will get also the percentage from the secondary receiver?

Example: 
Sender - $100
Primary Receiver - $90
Secondary Receiver - $10

If the sender asks for a refund, how will paypal handle it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I wanted to take a moment and empathize with you.  Integrating PayPal adaptive payments is one of the least fun things I've ever done.

Comment: Actually, had it working already ;) Working now on how to handle IPN messages in Adaptive Payment.